# How to select events from MySQL database after today's date

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to select the next three events from a MySQL database but can't seem to get it right. I need the next 3 events from today's date. I tried this and it doesn't work:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT *
    FROM events
    WHERE event_venue = 'venue_1'
    AND event_date >= $today LIMIT 3 ORDER BY event_date ASC
    ");
```

I also tried

```
AND event_date >= now() LIMIT 3 ORDER BY event_date ASC
```

but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

edit: date is stored in database as yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Show DDL. What does it mean "does not work" exactly? Does it return no data? If you skip date filter, does it return any data?

Comment: we need DDL for `events` table; i.e `show create table events` output.

Comment: is event_date stored as a varchar? If so, try using DATE or DATETIME instead

Answer (score 2):

Try below query: Limit will come at last.

```
SELECT *
    FROM EVENTS
    WHERE event_venue = 'venue_1'
    AND event_date >= CURDATE() ORDER BY event_date ASC  LIMIT 3;
```